# How to find leak in a hot tub

Tags: leak, hot-tub

I have a hot tub that I know is leaking.  The water level keeps dropping, and it always stops at the same spot.  The challenge is that there are 5 jets at the level where the water stops dropping, so I figure one of those is the problem, however after taking the sides off the tub, I see that the entire shell is encased in spray foam insulation covering almost all the plumbing.

Is there a trick to finding the source of my leak without having to rip apart all the insulation around my tub?

Comment: Are you sure it's not going out the drain?  If so, could you somehow plug each of the jets then, one by one, unplug them and see if the water level drops.

Comment: Dye in the water might show you where the leak is, though it might also make a mess.

Comment: @Fezter I don't think it's going out the drain, which is in the tub floor, since the tub stops leaking with about 2 feet of water still in it.

Comment: @Tester101 I was thinking about that too, and I'm fine with the mess, but the entire tub plumbing is encased in spray foam, so I won't be able to pinpoint where the leak is coming from without tearing all of that out first, which doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: Are you able to measure the pressure of the jets? If one of them has a poor connection or a crack which leaks water out then it should also leak what it is pushing under pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem and no, you have to take the sides off.  You need to do this soon because a leak can cause problems with wood rot.  You shouldn't have to take off the spray insulation, just fill it with water and start looking with a flashlight.

If you find no water leaks, then your problem is likely your tub drain.

Answer (score 0):

Leaks in that model have been found in the tubing embedded within the foam.  Search the web for answers.  I know I've seen photos of this.  Yes you will have to dig out the foam, repair the leak or cap off the tubing, then use spray can foam to replace what you've removed.